# Possible to write the code once for a specific set of different types?

Tags: c++11

I have a template class `TC` who's constructor takes parameters who's values are dependent on, as well as being of type `Tn`.

So, I want to create a helper template function `htf` that will call the same functions of a `Tn` object to generate a `TC` for a set of types `X0` to `Xn`.  The helper function takes only one parameter from that set.  Is it possible, perhaps with variadic templates, to write the function once for the set of types, instead of having to write the same function over and over again for each type?

Now, I could just use a template to allow all types, but I don't want that as there may be another function with the same name written for a specific type later that's not based on this `TC`.  And, IIRC I think *SFINAE* works with member functions, not *pure* functions.

This is just an idea in my head at the moment, that's why the question is very general.  However, here is roughly the code I'm thinking of, simplified, in an more concrete and in an over generalized fashion:

```
struct X0
{
  int value;
  int& fn() { return value; }
};

struct X1
{
  double value;
  double& fn() { return value; }
};

struct X2
{
  float value;
  float& fn() { return value; }
};

struct Y0 // don't accept this class in helper function
{
  int value;
  int& fn() { return value; }
};

template<typename T1, typename Tn>
class TC
{
  T1* m_pT1;
  Tn* m_pTn;
  TC(T1* pT1, Tn* pTn) : m_pT1(pT1), m_pTn(pTn) {}
  friend TC htf(Tn& tn);
public:
  ~TC() {}
};

// concrete functions:
TC<int,    X0> htf(C0& x) { return TC<int,    X0>(&x.fn(), &x); }
TC<double, X1> htf(C1& x) { return TC<double, X1>(&x.fn(), &x); }
TC<float,  X2> htf(C2& x) { return TC<float,  X2>(&x.fn(), &x); }

// or in an over generalized template function but it'll accept
// Y0 and others which I don't want:
template<typename X>
auto htf(X& x) -> TC<decltype(x.fn()), X>
{
  return TC<decltype(x.fn()), X>(&x.fn(), &x);
}
```

So the `htf` function that I want is to work for classes `X0`, `X1`, and `X2`, but not `Y0`.  However, I don't want it to interfere with any other function called `htf` that takes a parameter of type `Y0`, or any other type for that matter.

## Additional

Is it possible to make it so that the collection of accepted classes can also include template classes taking an specified (or unspecified) number of parameters?

Comment: I don't fully understand your problem but if you want to have a function only for a certain set of types then simple overloading is what you are looking for.

Comment: @bamboon, the concrete example shows simple overloading, but it requires that I do this for all the types that I want to do this for.  I'd rather have only one template function that does this, but using the over generalized template function does it for all, and that is not what I want either.  I want a middle ground.  One template function for a set of types.

Comment: SFINAE works for any function templates, not only member functions

Comment: @JonathanWakely Ok, then I need to generate a type set and iterate through them to see if the type is in that set.  Now to figure out how to do that.

Comment: No need to iterate anything, just specialize using a trait

Comment: @JonathanWakely, example?

Comment: See my answer. Iteration is how you deal with each element of a set at run-time, it's not necessary at compile-time, just let the compiler match the relevant specialization for the type.

Comment: @JonathanWakely, I know that you can iterate over a set using verdict templates. I was thinking that using that would make the code clearer as it would reduce the code noise.  Your answer is works, but I think I'm going to hold out for something that is more compact.

Answer (score 2):

Write a function that is only enabled when a trait is true, then specialize it for all the desired types.

```
template<typename T>
struct enable_htf : std::false_type { };

template<>
struct enable_htf<X0> : std::true_type { };

template<>
struct enable_htf<X1> : std::true_type { };

// etc.

template<typename T, bool enable = enable_htf<T>::value>
struct htf_helper { };

template<typename T>
struct htf_helper<T, true>
{
  using type = TC<decltype(std::declval<T&>().fn()), T>;
};

template<typename X>
typename htf_helper<X>::type
htf(X& x)
{
  return { &x.fn(), &x };
}
```

But it seems you want something like this instead:

```
template<typename Needle, typename... Haystack>
struct is_one_of;

template<typename Needle, typename Head, typename... Tail>
struct is_one_of<Needle, Head, Tail...>
: conditional<is_same<Needle, Head>::value, true_type,
              is_one_of<Needle, Tail...>>::type
{ };

template<typename Needle>
struct is_one_of<Needle> : false_type
{ };

template<typename X,
         typename Requires = typename enable_if<is_one_of<X, X0, X1, X2>::value>::type>
auto
htf(X& x) -> TC<decltype(x.fn()), X>
{
  return { &x.fn(), &x };
}
```

But personally I don't consider that clearer, even if `is_one_of` is reusable elsewhere.

Comment: This is interesting, but it's very verbose.  I was hoping for something that was more like a list of types to enable the function for.

Comment: The use of the `declval` is cool though. Didn't know of that one before. :)

Comment: Either overloading or something like this is how you enable code for a specific set of types in C++, if you're hoping for something else you'll need to use a different language. You can make it less verbose by hiding the same logic behind an existing library, such as Boost.MPL, but it won't be simpler as Boost.MPL would add *lots* of code.

Comment: True enough.  But I'll still wait.  Also, I think that your `htf_helper` template declaration class for the `htf` function is on the wrong side.  `X` hasn't been deduced yet so, I think you need to do: `template<typename X> auto htf(X& x) -> typename htf_helper<X>::type`

Comment: No, `X` is declared in the template parameter list, so can be used anywhere after that. See the edited answer for a variadic template that looks for a type in a variadic parameter pack.

Comment: Oh?  I thought deduction rules for template functions that returned a type based on the deduced type of its parameter required that the return type be on the right of the function signature.  This is much closer to what I am looking for.  Reusability is key as I have to do this more than once.  Just need to move the valid classes to a type of its own as I have several functions that will need this with the same set and other functions with other sets.  Perhaps I could derive a class from all valid types and check to see if the type has an IS_A relation.

Comment: No, you're wrong. You can use a name after it's declared. If you want to use the name `x` in the return type then you need to use a trailing-return-type, because that comes after the parameter list where `x` is declared. But my first solution only uses the name `X` in the return type, not `x`, and that is already declared, so the return type doesn't need to come after the parameter list. This has nothing to do with deduction, just the usual C++ rule that you can't use a name before it's declared.

Comment: Ah yes. That's because you used the `declval` which I didn't see before. :)

Comment: No, the return type of `htf` is just `typename htf_helper<X>::type` which only uses `X` ... oh I think see what you mean, `htf_helper` doesn't need to use `x` internally because it uses `declval`

Comment: I've run into a stumbling block.  The collection of classes can contain a template class of several parameters (lets say 2, but I think there is potential for more or less than that).  The `is_base_of` solution won't work for that it seems.  Is there a way for your list mechanism to accommodate such beasties?

Comment: Not easily, but the `enable_htf` version works fine with class templates, you can define a partial specialization: `template<typename T, typename U> struct enable_htf<some_class_template<T, U>> : true_type { };`

Answer (score 0):

This is an even more simplified version of my original question, but it relates to enabling a template function based on the type passed to it being part of a list of accepted types.

```
class A{};
class B{};
class C{};
class D{};
class collection1 : A, B, C {};
class collection2 : D {};

template<typename X>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<X, collection1>::value, X>::type fn(X x)
{
    return X();
}
```

Then the following would work appropriately:

```
fn(A()); // works
fn(B()); // works
fn(C()); // works
fn(D()); // compile time failure
```

Having a 2nd function like this:

```
template<typename X>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<X, collection2>::value, X>::type fn(X x)
{
    return X();
}
```

Would result in:

```
fn(A()); // works
fn(B()); // works
fn(C()); // works
fn(D()); // works
```

Using this method, I can enable function `fn` to work with types I want and not others and I can write the list with ease.  Also, this should be faster than iterating through a list of variadic template parameters.

Thanks [Jonathan Wakely](https://stackoverflow.com/users/981959/jonathan-wakely), you helped a lot in my thought process.  I just thought that this is simpler and can be made even clearer if I use a helper template which would encapsulate the `enable_if` clause which would be good as I have many other functions that would require this.

## Additional

Looks like this answer isn't good enough as I need to be able to determine if a template class is in the collection I'm looking for.