# How to get a SFINAE expression to work with template and non-template classes?

Tags: c++11, sfinae

I have made this for SFINAE:

```
// Type 'type' exists iff X is a base of COLLECTION
template<typename X, typename COLLECTION, typename RET_TYPE = void>
struct enable_if_is_base_of : std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<X, COLLECTION>::value, RET_TYPE>
{};
```

Which works well for something like this:

```
class A {}; class B {}; class C{};
class collection : A, B {};

template <typename X>
typename enable_if_is_base_of<X, collection>::type fn(X&& x) { }

int main() {

    fn(A());
    fn(B());
    // fn(C()); // Fails as expected
    return 0;
}
```

However, if I want `collection` to be derived from a template as well as non-template classes, I'm not sure how I would go about that.

Something like this:

```
                      class A {};
template <typename X> class B {};
                      class C {};
template <typename X> class D {};

template <typename X> class collection : A, B<X> {};

// Stuff where the magic happens
...

// Testing the magic
template <typename X> // or other template declaration
typename enable_if_is_base_of<X, collection>::type fn(X&& x) { }
// May require more than one fn() declaration.

int main() {

    fn(A());
    fn(B<int>());
    // fn(C()); // Fails to compile
    // fn(D<int>()); // Fails to compile
    return 0;
}
```

Bonus point if the collection class can derive from any class or class template with any number of template parameters. :)

Comment: You cannot check that a type `X` is a base class of some template class `collection<Y>` where `Y` is not known. That is fundamentally impossible, since `collection<Y>` could conceivably be a specialisation that unlike the primary template definition *does* derive from `X`. Do you perhaps want to check that if the class is `B<X>` for some type `X`, that `B<X>` is a base of `collection<X>`?

Comment: Do you mean [something like in this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25845536/3953764) ?

Comment: Could you add a use case for the trait you want?

Comment: Mmmm, not quite.  See this [demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4ac8b3b794847691).

Comment: @PiotrS. Added use case.

Comment: @Adrian and `C()` and `D<int>()` are rejected because none specialization of `collection<T>` derive from them ?

Comment: @PiotrS. Yes. Exactly.

Comment: @Adrian the linked solution checks the opposite (if a class template given as a template-template parameter is a base class of concrete type X), it's not possible to check if a template derives from some class, unless you can use a placeholder for a type template parameter, hoping there are no specializations of that class template that expose different behavior (deriving from other classes or not deriving at all)

Comment: Also keep in mind that even if there are no specialisations of `collection<T>`, there could still potentially be specialisations of `B<T>` that have `C` or `D<U>` (for some unknown `U`) as a base.

Comment: I see.  Well I need to determine if a type is part of a collection of types so that I can use SFINAE to disregard types not in the collection.  I wrote a question on this [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27669304/possible-to-write-the-code-once-for-a-specific-set-of-different-types), but I've discovered that I need it to apply to template classes as well.  Could you help?

Comment: @Adrian something like [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c9c7317bc0c836ac) ?

Comment: @Adrian or something like [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/33ee954c08490a01) instead ?

Comment: @PiotrS. Sort of.  Except the list can contain class templates and non-templates.   It would also be great if the list specified can be a type too so that I can use the same list in multiple places.

Comment: @Adrian you'd need to wrap template-template arguments, like [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a261e5aa196d1fe6), oterwise it's impossible to mix type template parameters with template template parameters

Comment: @PiotrS., check out my answer.  I was able to do the impossible. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much trying and testing I've come up with a solution:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<type_traits>
using namespace std;

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Place Holder Class
template <typename ...T>
class PH {};

// Select a Collection to Test On

// Since a collection is a template class that can derive from a non-template class
// or template classes of an arbitrary number of typename parameters, these 
// functions selects one instance of the collection, for which the base can be
// tested for.
template <
    template <template <typename...> class, typename...> class C
    , template <typename...> class TT
    , typename...T>
C<TT,T...> collection_selector(TT<T...>);

template <template <template <typename...> class, typename...> class C, typename T>
C<PH,T> collection_selector(T);

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Aliases the type to make it more readable
template <typename T, template <template <typename...> class, typename...> class C>
is_base_of<T, decltype(collection_selector<C>(declval<T&>()))> enable_if_is_base_of_truth_selector();

// Not doing a direct 'using' to a type because of a bug in VC++ 2013.
// See https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1069557/failed-to-deduce-type-for-template-function
template <typename T, template <template <typename...> class, typename...> class C>
using is_base_of_truth = decltype(enable_if_is_base_of_truth_selector<T, C>());

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Aliases the type to make it more readable
template <typename T, template <template <typename...> class, typename...> class C, typename RT>
typename enable_if<is_base_of<T, decltype(collection_selector<C>(declval<T&>()))>::value, RT>::type enable_if_is_base_of_selector();
//typename enable_if<is_base_of_truth<T, C>::value, RT>::type enable_if_is_base_of_selector();

// Not doing a direct 'using' to a type because of a bug in VC++ 2013.
// See https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1069557/failed-to-deduce-type-for-template-function
template <typename T, template <template <typename...> class, typename...> class C, typename RT = void>
using enable_if_is_base_of = decltype(enable_if_is_base_of_selector<T, C, RT>());

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Select type from list
template <unsigned int I, typename ...Ts>
struct items;

template <typename T, typename ...Ts>
struct items<0, T, Ts...>
{
    typedef T type;
};

template <unsigned int I, typename T, typename ...Ts>
struct items<I, T, Ts...> : items<I-1, Ts...>
{
};

template <unsigned int I>
struct items<I>
{
    typedef int type;
};

template <unsigned int I, typename ...Ts>
typename items<I, Ts...>::type get_item_selector();

template <unsigned int I, typename ...Ts>
using get_item = decltype(get_item_selector<I, Ts...>());

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Classes to test on
class A{};
template <typename T> class B{};
template <typename T0, typename T1> class BB{};
class C{};
template <typename T> class D{};
template <typename T0, typename T1> class DD{};

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Collection of valid types
template <
    template <typename...> class TT
    , typename...Ts>
class collection 
    : A                                        // class A
    , B<get_item<0,Ts...>>                     // class B<X>
    , BB<get_item<0,Ts...>, get_item<1,Ts...>> // class BB<Y, Z>
{};

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Function to enable on
template <typename T>
enable_if_is_base_of<T, collection> test(T&&)
{
}

int main()
{
    cout << "-------------------------------------------------" << endl;
    cout << "Should all be 1." << endl;
    cout << is_base_of_truth<A             , collection>::value << endl;
    cout << is_base_of_truth<B<char*>      , collection>::value << endl;
    cout << is_base_of_truth<BB<int, float>, collection>::value << endl;
    cout << "-------------------------------------------------" << endl;
    cout << "Should all be 0." << endl;
    cout << is_base_of_truth<C              , collection>::value << endl;
    cout << is_base_of_truth<D<char>        , collection>::value << endl;
    cout << is_base_of_truth<DD<int, float&>, collection>::value << endl;
    cout << "-------------------------------------------------" << endl;

    // These succeed to compile since C, D<X> and DD<Y, Z> are the base of collection
    test(A());
    test(B<int>());
    test(BB<int, long>());

    // These fail to compile since C, D<X> and DD<Y, Z> are NOT the base of collection
    //test(C());             // fails as expected
    //test(D<int>());        // fails as expected
    //test(DD<int, long>()); // fails as expected

}
```

[DEMO](http://cpp.sh/4wuq)

NOTE: I had to change the template of the `collection` so that it included a template as well.  This made life very interesting but it did make the final result more readable and made some interesting meta functions.