# Is it possible to change `B<get_item<0,Ts...>>` to `template_with_params<B, 1, ...Ts>`?

Tags: c++, c++11, sfinae

I was working on a SFINAE programme to remove function template instances from the programme if the parameter class or template class is not a base of the collection (see [How to get a SFINAE expression to work with template and non-template classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27722987/how-to-get-a-sfinae-expression-to-work-with-template-and-non-template-classes/27739293#27739293)):

```
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Classes to test on
class A{};
template <typename T> class B{};
template <typename T0, typename T1> class BB{};
class C{};
template <typename T> class D{};
template <typename T0, typename T1> class DD{};

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Collection of valid types
template <
    template <typename...> class TT
    , typename...Ts>
class collection 
    : A                                        // class A
    , B<get_item<0,Ts...>>                     // class B<X>
    , BB<get_item<0,Ts...>, get_item<1,Ts...>> // class BB<Y, Z>
{};

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Function to enable on
template <typename T>
enable_if_is_base_of<T, collection> test(T&&)
{    return enable_if_is_base_of<T, collection>();
}
```

Now I was wondering if the specifications of `B<X>` or `BB<Y,Z>` where they are defined as being base of `collection` can somehow become inverted from `BB<get_item<0,Ts...>, get_item<1,Ts...>>` to `template_with_params<BB, X, 2, ...Ts>` which returns a type of `BB<T0, T1>`, where `T0` is the first template parameter from `Ts...`, and `T1` is the 2nd template parameter from `Ts...`.  Also, if there are not enough elements in `Ts`, then a default `X` would be used for the rest. Possible?

Comment: No, I want `template_with_params<T, 1, Ts...>` to return `T<T0>`, `template_with_params<T, 2, Ts...>` to return `T<T0, T1>`, etc.

Comment: where `T0, T1` are from `Ts...` ?

Comment: is [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f8b126620fcb7ecc) what you want?

Comment: @PiotrS., except there needs to be default parameter types like `void` if there are not enough parameters.

Comment: is `void` customizable or hard-coded?

Comment: @PiotrS., sure, customizable. How much more complicated is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <utility>
#include <type_traits>
#include <tuple>

template <std::size_t... Is>
struct index_sequence {};

template <std::size_t N, std::size_t... Is>
struct make_index_sequence_h : make_index_sequence_h<N - 1, N - 1, Is...> {};

template <std::size_t... Is>
struct make_index_sequence_h<0, Is...> { using type = index_sequence<Is...>; };

template <std::size_t N>
using make_index_sequence = typename make_index_sequence_h<N>::type;

template <template <typename...> class T, typename D, std::size_t N, typename... Ts>
struct template_with_params_impl;

template <template <typename...> class T, typename D, std::size_t N, std::size_t... Is, std::size_t... Js, typename... Ts>
struct template_with_params_impl<T, D, N, index_sequence<Is...>, index_sequence<Js...>, Ts...>
{
    using type = T<typename std::tuple_element<Is, std::tuple<Ts...>>::type..., typename std::remove_reference<decltype(void(Js), std::declval<D>())>::type...>;
};

template <template <typename...> class T, typename D, std::size_t N, typename... Ts>
using template_with_params = typename template_with_params_impl<T, D, N, make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Ts) >= N ? N : sizeof...(Ts)>, make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Ts) >= N ? 0 : N - sizeof...(Ts)>, Ts...>::type;

// if you want `void' to be the hardcoded default parameter, use below alias instead:
// template <template <typename...> class T, std::size_t N, typename... Ts>
// using template_with_params = typename template_with_params_impl<T, void, N, make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Ts) >= N ? N : sizeof...(Ts)>, make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Ts) >= N ? 0 : N - sizeof...(Ts)>, Ts...>::type;
```

*Tests:*

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename... Ts>
struct B { void foo() { std::cout << 1; } };

int main()
{    
    template_with_params<B, void, 3, int> b{}; b.foo(); // 1

    static_assert(std::is_same< template_with_params<B, void, 3, int>, 
                                B<int, void, void> >{}, "!");

    static_assert(std::is_same< template_with_params<B, void, 1, int, float>, 
                                B<int> >{}, "!");
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/536a149973627ee5)

Comment: [This code](http://cpp.sh/5ey5m) should work on c++11.  I don't even see `std::index_sequence` referenced on the web yet from c++14.

Comment: @Adrian [here is a sample implementation](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/28f0f32a3a5dba63) , [index_sequence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/integer_sequence) is an alias of `integer_sequence`, probably not yet available in your libstdc++

Comment: Didn't work when trying to create object `template_with_params<B, 3, int>::type{}`.

Comment: Also tried that with your [sample implementation](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/28f0f32a3a5dba63) and it failed by blowing the compiler stack.

Comment: what is your compiler ?

Comment: I tried [here](http://cpp.sh/9wh) which is g++ 4.9.0 and the one you used [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8fee0a349229a29b)

Comment: @Adrian hold on, `template_with_params<B, 3, int>::type{}` is not valid because it requires *at least* `3` elements on the `Ts...` list. It works for me if you put there e.g. `template_with_params<B, 3, int, char, float>::type{}`

Comment: That's what I'm saying about defaults.  If there aren't enough, then use a specified default like `void`.

Comment: @Adrian I misunderstood the idea with defaults, let me correct this

Comment: Yeah, I see what happened, you got it reversed. This should be valid: `static_assert(std::is_same< template_with_params<B, void, 1, int, float, char>::type, B<int> >{}, "!")` and `static_assert(std::is_same< template_with_params<B, void, 3, int, float, char>::type, B<int, void, void> >{}, "!")`, *not* this `static_assert(std::is_same< template_with_params<B, void, 1, int, float, char>::type, B<int, void, void> >{}, "!")`.

Comment: As this is tagged as `c++11` and not `c++14`, you should post the code that will compile on `c++11`.

Comment: @Adrian almost everyone is aware of the possible implementation of `index_sequence` and its absence in C++11, I see no such need

Comment: Everyone but those who don't. :)  Sorry, it's not part of `c++11`, so I can't mark it as resolved.

Comment: @Adrian I've addded C++11 version + some simplification

Comment: Gah! VC++ is garbage!  Won't compile.  After doing the workaround for the `using name_t = ...::type` => `...::type type_selector(); using name_t = decltype(type_selector())` workaround, I got a `error C3546: '...': there are no parameter packs available to expand` when trying to specialize `template_with_params_impl`. Why MS?  WHY!! >:(

Comment: @Adrian what does `type_selector` declare as return type (exactly) ?

Comment: The type that was originally being aliased with the using.  That is the general idiom that I use and what you showed to work.

Comment: @Adrian yes, but do you specify the template argumetns, like `decltype(type_selector<B, int, 3, int>())`?, how does it look like?

Comment: guess you got stumped too, eh?

Answer (score 1):

It can be implemented with a recursion, applying one parameter after another:

```
// Apply a single type parameter to a template, producing a new template
template<template<typename...> class TT, typename T>
struct apply_partial {
   template<typename... Ts>
   using type = TT<T, Ts...>;
};

// Apply parameters from I upto N, one after another, using apply_partial
template<template<typename...> class TT, std::size_t I, std::size_t N, typename... Ts>
struct apply_seq {
   typedef typename apply_seq<
         apply_partial<TT, get_item<I, Ts...>>::template type,
         I+1, N, Ts...
      >::type type;
};

template<template<typename...> class TT, std::size_t N, typename... Ts>
struct apply_seq<TT, N, N, Ts...> {
   typedef TT<> type;
};

// Main template
template<template<typename...> class TT, std::size_t N, typename... Ts>
using template_with_params = typename apply_seq<TT, 0, N, Ts...>::type;
```

It compiles but I haven't tested it extensively. Additional features like defaults can also be added with additional template parameters and specializations for `apply_seq`.

For a `void` default, you'd add this case:

```
template<template<typename...> class TT, std::size_t I, std::size_t N>
struct apply_seq<TT, I, N> {
   typedef typename apply_seq<TT, I, N, void>::type type;
};
```

Comment: This is nice too.  But what type is `template_with_params<B, 3, int>`?  Can  it be made so that `template_with_params<B, X, 3, int>` is equivalent to `B<int, X, X>`?

Comment: Adding that void default didn't work for me.  See [here](http://cpp.sh/3dfd).  BTW, how does `apply_partial<TT, get_item<I, Ts...>>::template type` work?

Comment: I've not seen `apply_partial<TT, get_item<I, Ts...>>::template type` before.  How does it get parsed?

Comment: @Adrian: The `template` in the end tells the compiler that the `type` in `apply_partial<TT, get_item<I, Ts...>>::type` is a template. It's similar to the situations where you need an additional `typename` to tell the compiler that some dependent name is a type. See also [Where and why do I have to put the “template” and “typename” keywords?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords).

Comment: Ok, so I now understand what it says.  I'm a bit fuzzy as to how it works (not the template keyword, just everything else ;) )  How does this build a list of types? The 2nd `apply_seq` is the final case. The 1st must be the builder and does so by using the template type alias in `apply_partial`, but I can't see how it's done. My head is about to explode. o.O